# Mercurial : Avoid commiting if pending incoming or how to prevent multiple heads?

Tags: mercurial

Im using mercurial and we are finding problems with the multiple heads.

IM NOT ASKING HOW TO RESOLVE IT. I already know.

The question is, how can I configure mercurial (if possible) to prevent commiting without pulling and merging?.

How can I prevent users creating multiple heads?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Let me get this straight clear, as I'm starting to worry about me not understanding mercurial's way.

I create a respository, lets call it Projects.
I push my data on it, creating a Revision 1
Then I modify data, creating Revision 2

My coworker downloads the repo, and now has a local rev2
I modify my data (Rev2) and commit
My coworker modifies his local (rev2).

And now, my coworker can't push his work cause it creates a new head. 
But, if he first Pulls the code he gets my rev2' and can proceed to push a modified rev3.
The problem is, i dont want him to be able to create this new head, but, force him to PULL my source, before he commits, so there is only one head.

As Mathiasdm said, I'm starting to think that this is not possible, as our local rev2 differs?
Im using mercurial wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to? You can't merge if you haven't committed. Why do you want to avoid commit, pull, merge? Temporarily, after pulling, you will have multiple heads. This is completely normal. The problem comes if you *push* multiple heads, but that's easily solved by merging first. Why do you want to prevent committing?

Comment: I was asking is if there is a way to prevent my coworkers to commit without Pulling first. Or i am messing something here?

Comment: Committing without having to pull and merge first is an inherent feature of Mercurial.
It sounds like you want to move to a model that's more similar to Subversion, or am I misunderstanding?

I don't really grasp the reason why you want to do this. There's no way to force such a workflow in Mercurial, except if you can figure out a way to get all users to install custom hooks that force this (something which I would _not_ recommend!).

Comment: Let me get this straight clear, as I'm starting to worry about me not understanding mercurial's way. 

I create a respository, lets call it Projects.

Comment: I comment on the question for better clarification, but Im starting to think that it is not possible?

Comment: Unlike centralized systems like Subversion, a "commit" is not relevant to your repository until a "push". Anyone can commit anyhting and you can "refuse" to pull those changes. That's how it works on DVCS. So you want to prevent "push"es that create a new head instead of commits.

Comment: but, wouldnt the commits create a new head? sorry if im noob to Hg

Comment: after being pushed i mean

Comment: As has been mentioned, the workflow you are trying to prevent is exactly the workflow that Mercurial is designed for. Check out http://hginit.com/, it might be helpful!

Comment: You selected wrong way to work with Mercurial and lost independence of workplaces. Re-think about habits, while it isn't too late

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want on Linux/UNIX:

```
[hooks]
precommit = ! hg incoming
```

That works because as `hg help incoming` shows incoming returns 0 if there are incoming changes.  And as `man hgrc` shows if a `precommit` hook returns 0 the commit can proceed.  Add a negation and Bob's your uncle.

None of this, of course guarantees there won't be multiple heads, but it makes sure you can't commit without checking if someone else has pushed one already.  Good luck getting your friend to install the hook though.